# redirect the screen output into a file

Tags: python-3.x

I got a question about redirect the screen output into a single file. Here is my code to print the screen output:

```
for O,x,y,z,M,n in coordinate:
    print(O,x,y,z,M,n)
```

And the screen output looks like:

```
O 0 0 0 ! 1
O 1 0 0 ! 2 
O 2 0 0 ! 3
```

So how can I redirect all the data into a single file and in the same format, just like the screen output. Because it will be mush faster to get all the data rather than waiting for the screen output to finish.
I tried`for point in coordinate:
        file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in point))` but output file became:

```
O 0 0 0 ! 0O 1 0 0 ! 1O 2 0 0 ! 2O 3 0 0 ! 3O 4 0 0 ! 4O 5 0 0 ! 5O 6 0 0 ! 6O
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply redirect the console output to a file
$ `python yourscript.py > output.txt`

No code changes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function has a keyword-only parameter `file` which specifies the file object to be written to. That's the easiest way to go:

```
for O,x,y,z,M,n in coordinate:
    print(O,x,y,z,M,n,file=output_file)
```

The reason your `write` code wasn't working is that you were not putting a newline character at the end of each entry. You could also try fixing that:

```
file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in point) + '\n')
```